# import a dictionary built at run-time

Tags: python

My code is structured as follows:

```
main.py
utils.py
blah.py
```

The `main` module uses argparse to read in the location of a configurations yaml file which is then loaded as a dictionary. Is there a way for `utils` and `blah` to import this built-up dictionary?

Edit: I tried using `from main import config` (config being the dictionary I built) but I get `ImportError: cannot import name 'config' from 'main'`

Edit2: Main imports the other 2 modules - apologies for leaving out this very important detail

Comment: Why can't you `import main`? Obviously, run the parser and get the config, if it's not done in `main`'s global scope.

Comment: Does main import the other modules?  If so, then they can't import main, because that is circular imports.

Comment: You could pass the dictionary to `utils` and `blah` as necessary, or have a separate e.g. `other` module that loads the dictionary and `from other import my_dict` in each module for using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend making another file, say, `globals.py`. Import this in `main`, `utils`, and `blah`, and set properties in it to be recalled by the other modules. For example:

> globals.py

```
configs = {}
```

> main.py

```
import .globals
...
user_configs = yaml.load('user/entered/path.yml')
globals.configs.update(user_configs)  # modifies the global `configs` variable
```

> utils.py

```
import .globals
...
# need to use one of the configs for something:
try:
    relevant_config = globals.configs['relevant_config']
except KeyError:
    print("User did not input the config field 'relevant_config'")
```

All modules will be able to see the same `globals` instance, thus allowing you to use what are effectively global variables across your program.

---

You could simply save `configs` as a gobal variable in `main.py` and have `utils.py` and `blah.py` import `.main`, but having a designated module for this is cleaner and clearer than to have other modules importing the main module.

Answer (score 1):

Just do

```
import main
```

and use it as

```
main.dictionary
```

That should do it!